# Problema con formulario dinamico

Tags: javascript, formularios

tengo un formulario, la idea es que uno digite la cantidad y se agreguen inputs, pero necesito que una vez agregados cada uno de ellos haga lo mismo(contexto: el primero es para los discos y los otros para las canciones)...intento usar el mismo codigo (con retoques), entiendan que estoy empezando xd, y no funciona...probe algunas cosas q no dieron resultado...se me hace dificil porque yo creo el div o la seccion con los inputs mediante js y estaria intentando no usar html, quizas ahi este fallando, agradeceria alguien me pueda guiar ya que no se como buscar esta misma situacion en otros tutoriales, de antemano muchas gracias

```js
'use strict'

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    let select = document.querySelector("#numdiscos");
    let i = "";
    let seccionesDiscos = document.querySelector("#disco");
    let seleccionado = document.querySelector("#seleccionardiscos");
    seleccionado.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        seccionesDiscos.innerHTML = '';
        if (select.value >= 0 && select.value <= 5) {
         for (i = 0; i < select.value; i++) {
            createSeccionesDiscos();
        }
        }
    });

    function createSeccionesDiscos() {
        let element = document.createElement('div');
        element.innerHTML = `
        <div class="form-group canciones">
        <label>¿Cuántas canciones tiene el disco ${i + 1}?</label>
        <input type="number" name="numeroDiscos" min="1" max="30" class="form-control cds" required>
        <button type="submit" onclick="crearCanciones()" class="btn btn-success discos seleccionarCanciones">Ok</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        `;
    seccionesDiscos.appendChild(element);
    }
    });

function crearCanciones(event) {
if (event.target && event.target.className == 'seleccionarCanciones') {
    let cantCancion = document.querySelector(".cds");
    let x = "";
    let seccionesCanciones = document.querySelector(".canciones");
    let seleccionando= document.querySelector(".seleccionarCanciones")
    seleccionando.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    seccionesCanciones.innerHTML = '';
    if (cantCancion.value >= 0 && cantCancion.value <= 5) {
     for (x = 0; x < cantCancion.value; x++) {
        createSecciones();
    }
    } 
    }); 
    function createSecciones() {
        let elemento = document.createElement('div');
        elemento.innerHTML = `
        <div class="form-group">
        <p>Nombre del album</p>
        <input type="text" name="nombre-encuesta" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="canciones"></div>
        `;
    seccionesCanciones.appendChild(elemento);
    }  
    }
    }
    document.addEventListener('click',crearCanciones,true );
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
         <label for="numdiscos">¿Cuántos discos/volúmenes tiene tu álbum?</label><br>
         <input type="number" id="numdiscos" name="numeroDiscos" min="0" max="5" class="form-control cds" required>
         <button type="submit" id="seleccionardiscos" class="btn btn-success discos">Ok</button>
         <br>
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div id="disco"></div>
         <div class="canciones"></div>
```

No agrego lo que intente porque realmente es muy parecido, use classes y no ids, trate de diferenciarlos con condicionales y no se me ocurrio mucho mas... se agradece cualquier sugerencia, no estoy pidiendo el codigo entero pero si alguna guia clara de donde buscar o algo por el estilo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo que pusiste hace lo que pedis.. donde esta el problema?

Comment: Hola, si, disculpen las torpezas, pense que habia quedado claro...la primera vez si, con la cantidad de albumes..yo quisiera saber como hacer que cada uno de esos inputs que se crean hagan lo mismo y creen otros inputs...probe modificando el codigo del primero pero no hace nada, si es necesario lo agrego, ahora edito la pregunta

Comment: Agrega la funcion crear canciones, que es justamente la que deberia crear los nuevos inputs....

Comment: ahi agregue a la pregunta el codigo que intento usar para que cada input cree independientemente otros inputs...es muy parecido al que si funciona

Comment: Bien.. ahora tenes un error bien claro, que deberia estar en la pregunta. Seguramente no estas encontrando alguno de los controles que estas buscando.. verificaste 1 a 1 que los estuvieras encontrando?

Comment: creeria que si, sigo revisando, con el event tengo problemas, en la consola me manda a la primera linea del html                                                              crearCanciones http://127.0.0.1:5500/mailer9/js/inputs.js:80
onclick http://127.0.0.1:5500/mailer9/index.html:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He aquí la solución. Traté de dejar el código lo más parecido a como tu lo tenías.

Primero añadí el id "canciones" al div donde se insertarán las canciones del álbum.

```
<div id="canciones" class="canciones"></div>
```

Ahora, en el JS añadí el id "cds${i}" al input del número de discos generado dinámicamente con el for.

```
<input id="cds${i}" type="number" name="numeroDiscos" min="1" max="30" class="form-control cds" required>
```

Después añadí el id "crearCanciones${i}" al botón creado por la función "createSeccionesDiscos".

```
<button id="crearCanciones${i}" type="submit" class="btn btn-success discos seleccionarCanciones">Ok</button>
```

Después creé una variable llamando al id de dicho botón, para que al detectar el click se ejecute la función "crearCanciones" con el valor de "i".

```
let crearCancionesBtn = document.querySelector(`#crearcanciones${i}`);
crearCancionesBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {crearCanciones(i)});
```

En esta función hice varios cambios. Primero cambie los "." por "#" para que seleccione los elementos por su id.

```
let cantCancion = document.querySelector("#cds${i}");
let x = "";
let seccionesCanciones = document.querySelector("#canciones");
let seleccionando = document.querySelector("#seleccionarCanciones");
seccionesCanciones.innerHTML = '';
```

De ahí dejé el if y el for que ejecutan la función createSecciones, la cual dejé de la siguiente manera:

```
function createSecciones()
{
  let elemento = document.createElement('div');
  elemento.innerHTML = `
  <div class="form-group">
  <p>Nombre del album</p>
  <input type="text" name="nombre-encuesta" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="canciones"></div>
  `;
  seccionesCanciones.appendChild(elemento);
}
```

De esta manera logra crearse el input del nombre del álbum al darle click al botón de "ok" para cada elemento del numero de canciones generado dinámicamente. Ya será tarea tuya organizarlos para que queden bien en el documento y hacerlo de manera más optimizada.

El código HTML queda de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="numdiscos">¿Cuántos discos/volúmenes tiene tu álbum?</label><br>
     <input type="number" id="numdiscos" name="numeroDiscos" min="0" max="5" class="form-control cds" required>
     <button type="submit" id="seleccionardiscos" class="btn btn-success discos">Ok</button>
     <br>
     </div>
     <hr>
     <div id="disco"></div>
     <div id="canciones" class="canciones"></div>
```

y el JavaScript de esta manera:

'use strict'

```
window.addEventListener('load', function ()
{
  let select = document.querySelector("#numdiscos");
  let i = "";
  let seccionesDiscos = document.querySelector("#disco");
  let seleccionado = document.querySelector("#seleccionardiscos");
  seleccionado.addEventListener('click', function (e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    seccionesDiscos.innerHTML = '';
    if (select.value >= 0 && select.value <= 5)
    {
     for (i = 0; i < select.value; i++)
     {
        createSeccionesDiscos(i);
     }
    }
  });
  function createSeccionesDiscos(i)
  {
    let element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = `
    <div class="form-group canciones">
    <label>¿Cuántas canciones tiene el disco ${i + 1}?</label>
    <input id="cds${i}" type="number" name="numeroDiscos" min="1" max="30" class="form-control cds" required>
    <button id="crearCanciones${i}" type="submit" class="btn btn-success discos seleccionarCanciones">Ok</button>
    </div>
    <hr>`;
    seccionesDiscos.appendChild(element);
    let crearCancionesBtn = document.querySelector(`#crearCanciones${i}`);
    crearCancionesBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {crearCanciones(i)});
  }
  function crearCanciones(i)
  {
      let cantCancion = document.querySelector(`#cds${i}`);
      let x = "";
      let seccionesCanciones = document.querySelector("#canciones");
      let seleccionando = document.querySelector("#seleccionarCanciones");
      seccionesCanciones.innerHTML = '';
      if (cantCancion.value >= 0 && cantCancion.value <= 5)
      {
        for (x = 0; x < cantCancion.value; x++)
        {
          createSecciones();
        }
      }
      function createSecciones()
      {
        let elemento = document.createElement('div');
        elemento.innerHTML = `
        <div class="form-group">
        <p>Nombre del album</p>
        <input type="text" name="nombre-encuesta" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="canciones"></div>
        `;
        seccionesCanciones.appendChild(elemento);
      }
  }
});
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo:)

Comment: Amigo, estoy viendo el codigo, y funciona en parte, ya que cada valor que ingreso reemplaza al anterior...en la parte de crear canciones...si en la primera pongo 3 y a la segunda 2, me resta un input, no me lo suma...pero si funcionan todos los botones cosa que yo no pude hacer, voy a seguir mirando a ver si lo descifro, quizas lo copie mal de aqui...muchas gracias por el aporte bro!

Comment: ya lo solucione, habia que ponerle la variable "i" en dos partes del codigo, de verdad muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

lo dejo por si alguno busca algo parecido...es basicamente lo mismo que escribio darkem mas arriba, pero le hice un pequeño retoque en la ultima seccion del codigo para que se muestre cada cancion debajo del input que le corresponde

```
'use strict'
 window.addEventListener('load', function (){
 let select = document.querySelector("#numdiscos");
 let i = "";
 let seccionesDiscos = document.querySelector("#disco");
 let seleccionado = document.querySelector("#seleccionardiscos");
 seleccionado.addEventListener('click', function (e){
 e.preventDefault();
 seccionesDiscos.innerHTML = '';
 if (select.value >= 0 && select.value <= 5)
 {
 for (i = 0; i < select.value; i++)
 {
    createSeccionesDiscos(i);
 }
 }
 });
 function createSeccionesDiscos(i)
 {
 let element = document.createElement('div');
 element.innerHTML = `
 <div class="form-group canciones">
 <label>¿Cuántas canciones tiene el disco ${i + 1}?</label>
 <input id="cds${i}" type="number" name="numeroDiscos" min="1" max="30"  class="form-control cds" required>
 <button id="crearCanciones${i}" type="submit" class="btn btn-success discos seleccionarCanciones">Ok</button>
 </div>
 <hr>
 <div id="canciones${i}"></div>
 `;
 seccionesDiscos.appendChild(element);
 let crearCancionesBtn = document.querySelector(`#crearCanciones${i}`);
 crearCancionesBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {crearCanciones(i)});
 }
 function crearCanciones(i)
 {
  let cantCancion = document.querySelector(`#cds${i}`);
  let x = "";
  let seccionesCanciones = document.querySelector(`#canciones${i}`);
  let seleccionando = document.querySelector("#seleccionarCanciones");
  seccionesCanciones.innerHTML = '';
  if (cantCancion.value >= 0 && cantCancion.value <= 5)
  {
    for (x = 0; x < cantCancion.value; x++)
    {
      createSecciones();
    }
    }
    function createSecciones()
    {
    let elemento = document.createElement(`div`);
    elemento.innerHTML = `
    <div class="form-group">
    <p>Nombre del album</p>
    <input type="text" name="nombre-encuesta" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <hr>
    
    `;
    seccionesCanciones.appendChild(elemento);
  }
  }
  });
```

El html queda igual, pido disculpas por el frankeinstein que hice con class, ids y names xd